# Create new column based on condition of values in two other data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm new to python. I have a feeling there is a quick fix, but nothing has seemed quick to me yet.

I have a 150,000+ row dataframe, `data`. Within it are two series: `gridcode` and `CH4_Flux` among others. I want to create a new categorical column, called `category` that assigns a categorical identifier to each row based on the four conditions shown here:

```
cat1 = data[(data.gridcode <= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux >= threshAM)]
cat2 = data[(data.gridcode >= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux >= threshAM)]
cat3 = data[(data.gridcode <= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux <= threshAM)]
cat4 = data[(data.gridcode >= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux <= threshAM)]
```

where `threshAV` is a predesignated threshold for `gridcode`, and `threshAM` is a predesignated threshold for `CH4_Flux`. Essentially either both exceed the threshold, neither exceed, or one or the other exceeds. Preferably the categorical labels would simply be the integers 1,2,3, and 4 respectively following the logic of `cat1`,`cat2`,`cat3`,and `cat4` above.

I have tried `for` loops and `if` and `where` statements but have struck out.

When experimenting with `for` loops, I commonly get the error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Thank you in advance for any advice or direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for new columns by multiple boolean masks:

```
#removed filtering by data[]
m1 = (data.gridcode <= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux >= threshAM)
m2 = (data.gridcode >= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux >= threshAM)
m3 = (data.gridcode <= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux <= threshAM)
m4 = (data.gridcode >= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux <= threshAM)

data['category'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3, m4], [1,2,3,4])
```

Or:

```
data['category'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3, m4], ['cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4'])
```

Comment: This did not work for me. `data['category'] = np.select([cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4], [1,2,3,4])` returned `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

Comment: Yes the error was `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

Comment: @celder88 - Is possible add some data samples?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You want to see a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: @celder88 - I think I see problem, you need remove `data[]` form `cat1 = data[(data.gridcode <= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux >= threshAM)]` to `cat1 = (data.gridcode <= threshAV) & (data.CH4_Flux >= threshAM)`, check my answer

Comment: @celder88 - then working `data['category'] = np.select([cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4], [1,2,3,4])`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael! Good catch. If you have a minute, can you explain what the difference is when including the extra `data[ ]` as in the original `cat1`,`cat2`, etc.. code? And why this caused a problem?

Comment: @celder88 - Sure, if use `data[mask]` it is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and output is new filtered DataFrame by mask - filter by True values. If it remove, get only mask - Series with True or False values.